# (SQL) how to get the number of the entry in the queue?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
topic VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
priority TINYINT NOT NULL default 1,
created DATETIME); 

INSERT INTO tickets (id, topic, priority, created) VALUES
(1, 'kin23oi5n2', 3, '2018-05-27 16:00:54'),
(2, 'ewbrv32b3', 2, '2018-05-27 16:00:54'),
(3, 'aern23523', 1, '2018-05-27 16:01:15'),
(4, '4bt43t3', 5, '2018-05-27 16:01:15'),
(5, '32n523n5235n235t3n4', 4, '2018-05-27 16:01:39'),
(6, 'e2nr2n23n5235n23n523', 3, '2018-05-27 16:01:39');
```

I'm running a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tickets` order by `priority` ASC, `created` desc;
```

How do I get the row number with id 5 in this result using sql?

update:

`SELECT count(*) as pos FROM`tickets`WHERE ...;`
As a result, we obtain `pos`
I try to make that my result was similar to this but contained number of a line of the necessary row(id 5 for example).

in other words I want to get the number of the queue entry

Comment: You should add in example data as formatted text not as image. Which MySQL version?... `SELECT VERSION()`... Also add expected results as formatted text

Comment: row_number{} doesn't exist in mysql. If you mean how do you get the /row/ with id=5, then  SELECT * FROM `tickets` where id=5 will do it, but I assume you mean something more complicated than that.

Comment: version 5.7.21-20-beget-5.7.21-20-1-log
Yes, I need a row_number analog in mysql

Comment: " I need a row_number analog in mysql" Plenty Stackoverflow posts contain this just search "MySQL simulate row number". or something like that

Comment: "row_number{} doesn't exist in mysql" yes it does @MandyShaw MySQL 8 is released. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

Comment: Very useful article
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

But I do not need to add the column with the line number to the result, but return the result as the line number

Comment: Did you read mine first comment? We can't help you without example data and without expected results.

Comment: fixed. Use mysql version 8 is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, here is the answer

```
SELECT num FROM

(SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, id
FROM
    tickets order by `priority` ASC, `created` desc) as tmp_table WHERE id = 6;
```

But now there was another question. How is this implemented in Larabel 5.6?

UP
And he did it.